# Loop prompt if a value is empty / wrong?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple rock, paper, exercise on console (from The Odin Project) and I am stucked in some point. I want the prompt that selects rock, paper or scissors to keep showing if the user input is empty or wrong (if is a different string from the variable `choices`) and I'm not getting the reuslt I want, the alert shows, yes, but it shows whether if you input a correct value, a wrong value or if you left it empty and the prompt also finishes after the loop for ends which I only want to finish if the input is "rock", "paper" or "scissors".

Can someone enlight me here? I'm just blank.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerName = "";

function getComputerChoice() {
    let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
    console.log(random);
    return random;
}


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    
    
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return "It's a tie";
    } else if (playerSelection === "rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
        if (computerSelection === "paper") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    }
    
}

function playerChoice() {
    const userChoice = prompt("Rock, paper, scissors").toLowerCase();

    if (userChoice == null || userChoice !== choices) {
        alert("Empty or wrong choice!");
    } else if (choices.includes(userChoice)) {
        return userChoice;
    }
}

function getPlayerName() {
    playerName = prompt("What is your name?");
    return playerName;
}

function game () {
    getPlayerName();
    console.log(`Welcome ${playerName}`)

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
        const playerSelection = playerChoice();
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    }
    
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        return "Game over! Player wins!";
    } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
        return "Game over! Player loses!";
    } else {
        return "Game over, draw!";
    }
}

console.log(game());
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you wanted to loop the promt in `playerChoice`, where is your loop?

Comment: Btw, using recursion might be simpler and more straightforward than a loop here

Comment: Hi  @Bergi I don't know how to use recursion yet (haven't reach to that point), so, maybe I should use it inside the loop of game or even create a new loop? But I want to loop only if the value is wrong or empty, also, seems like the alert shows even if the value is correct so the if basically doesn't work as I want, right?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll want a new loop inside `playerChoice`

Comment: Oh, using a while should do the work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're checking whether the input is the same as the array `choices`. using the include function here will check that the user's choice is in the array

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let playerName = "";

function getComputerChoice() {
    let random = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
    console.log(random);
    return random;
}


function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    
    
    if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
        return "It's a tie";
    } else if (playerSelection === "rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "paper") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === "paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    } else if (playerSelection === "scissors") {
        if (computerSelection === "paper") {
            playerScore++;
            return `${playerName} wins! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}!`;
        } else if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            computerScore++;
            return `${playerName} lose! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}!`;
        }
    }
    
}

function playerChoice() {
    const userChoice = prompt("Rock, paper, scissors").toLowerCase();
    console.log(choices.includes(userChoice))
    if (userChoice == null || !choices.includes(userChoice)) {
        alert("Empty or wrong choice!");
    } else if (choices.includes(userChoice)) {
        return userChoice;
    }
}

function getPlayerName() {
    playerName = prompt("What is your name?");
    return playerName;
}

function game () {
    getPlayerName();
    console.log(`Welcome ${playerName}`)

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
        const playerSelection = playerChoice();
        console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    }
    
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        return "Game over! Player wins!";
    } else if (playerScore < computerScore) {
        return "Game over! Player loses!";
    } else {
        return "Game over, draw!";
    }
}

console.log(game());
```

Edit: Also you might want to change this line as a null input won't have the attribute `.toLowerCase()`

```js
const userChoice = prompt("Rock, paper, scissors").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Oh, sweet, thank you, so I basically should check if the userChoice NOT includes choices content instead of simply comparing if not equal.

About the .toLowerCase() thing, how's that? Should I create a new variable and set the content of it so I can pass the toLowerCase()?

Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah, so if you just do `!choices.includes()` that will return false if it's in the array. As for the `.toLowerCase()` you can have an if statement at the start of the function that returns if `playerChoice == null`

Comment: Sweet, now I get it, thank you very much for the explanation.